# PHP Forms With JQuery Requiring to press submit twice

Tags: php, jquery, forms

So I want to replace the form submission with a thank you message after you submit, I need the PHP because this will eventually deal with databases in that php, however right now... The only way it works, is that is Type in a name, press submit. It goes back to a blank form, enter nothing (nothing in address) and submit again and it works...

right now the only way i could think of making it work would be some dummy checkbox where when checked value changes the post is sent. However i don't think that will pass with my groupmates

wondering how i can make it only have to submit once.

Index.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php include_once "thankyou.php"; ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("document").ready(function() {
            $("#ContactUs_Submit").click(function(evt) {
                <?php $inputName = $_POST["ContactUs_Name"]; ?>
                $("#ContactUs_CommentsDiv").replaceWith("<?php 
                thankyou($inputName); ?>");
                return false;
            });

        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="ContactUs_CommentsDiv">
            <form method="post">
                <!-- WITH JQUERY USE SINGLE URL, WITH PAGES-->

                <label for="ContactUs_Name">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="ContactUs_Name" id="ContactUs_Name" />
                <br/>
                <Label for="ContactUs_Email">Email: </Label>
                <input type="email" name="ContactUs_Email" id="ContactUs_Email" />
                <br/>

                <input id="ContactUs_Submit" type="submit">
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

thankyou.php

```
<?php
function thankyou($name) {
echo "<p> Thank you for your input ";
 //if ($_POST["ContactUs_Name"] != "") {
            //  echo " " . $_POST["ContactUs_Name"];
        //  }
if ($name != ""){
    echo $name;
}
echo "!";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just use AJAX to do this?